# GIT - incorrect characters in file path

Tags: git, repository, character

I've got a problem with one of my git repositories. Problem is illegal charactes which exists in file paths.

Git bash:
[image: git bash,]

The files all the time exists as "unstaged changes" - even if i do `git add`.

In Tortoise repository explorer it looks like this:
[image: Tortoise repository explorer]

I can not delete the files using git rm beacause the files does not exists in repository (files which contains illegal characters).

Is there any way to delete the files with incorrect characters from repository ? It's really annoying when after `git status` there is n unstaged files...

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: may be use gitignore for those files

Comment: Git itself has no problem with nearly arbitrary path name strings, i.e., they're not "illegal" to Git. It's your *OS* that has an issue with the names. Git has a few (not many) built-in workarounds for some specific OSes, so it may help if you name your OS.

Comment: I use Windows 10. I have to point out that the file with unkown character does not exists in file system.